# Android TV apps Design: Video detail & horizontal list of vidoes

Tags: android, android-tv, leanback

We are developing an android tv app in which we need a horizontal lists of videos and on top of the screen there will be a view with some information related to video.
So as user selects different videos the top part of screen will be updated with the relevant detail of video.[image: Just like the sample picture]
We are using leanback library for android tv. I have checked the DetailSupportFragment but
this fragment seems to cover the detail part on top of screen once user navigates using D-pad. What we want is that top detail part should always be visible.
Any idea about how DetailSupportFragment can be customized or is there any other alternate solution.

Answer (score 0):

So I did it by using standard Android sdk views, mainly through recyclerview in grid layout format.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved it and below is my main activity xml looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#000000"
    >
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/title_layout"
        android:name="com.stack.plextv.HeaderTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
    <FrameLayout
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/main_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title_layout"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        tools:deviceIds="tv"
        >
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

In the `FrameLayout` I will load a fragment which extended from `VerticalGridSupportFragment`, which basically an Card Presenter list.

> fragment_header_title.xml

header title fragment wil have text & image to give faded look I have used `FadingEdgeLayout` [link](https://github.com/bosphere/Android-FadingEdgeLayout) which is an fragment class and below is the layout & assgin in main activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        ><!--        android:background="@color/icon_background"-->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title_content_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="16dp"
            tools:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="36sp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed-medium"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title_content_description"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:text=""
            android:textSize="19sp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed-medium"

            />
    </LinearLayout>
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:requiresFadingEdge="horizontal"
        >
        <com.bosphere.fadingedgelayout.FadingEdgeLayout
            android:id="@+id/fading_edge_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:fel_edge="top|left|bottom"
            app:fel_size_top="50dp"
            app:fel_size_bottom="50dp"
            app:fel_size_right="50dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/title_content_thumbnail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            />
        </com.bosphere.fadingedgelayout.FadingEdgeLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[Header-layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fL73.jpg)